# Using code sample in numbered/bulleted lists

Tags: bug

Whilst posting an answer on SO, I noticed that code sample formatting did not work correctly when posting snippets of code in numbered or order lists. For example:

1. Point one

   public class TwitterConnection {
           private string _consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerKey");
           private string _consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerSecret");
           private string _accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("accessToken");
           private string _accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("accessTokenSecret");

   ```
       private IHubContext _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TwitterHub>();

       public TwitterConnection()
       {
           // Access the filtered stream
           var filteredStream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();

           filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => 
           { 
               _context.Clients.All.broadcast(args.Tweet.Text);
           };

           filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();

       }
   ```

   }

   2. Point two

As you can see, the code sample feature does not work when included in a list. Does anyone know of any way around this? Or am I just being stupid?

Feel free to edit, to try and replicate the bug

Comment: In code lists, you need 4 extra spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just remember you need extra indentation for the numbered list.

Your example, quoted and corrected:

> Whilst posting an answer on SO, I noticed that code sample formatting
>   did not work correctly when posting snippets of code in numbered or
>   order lists. For example:
>
> 1. Point one
>
>    ```cs
>    public class TwitterConnection {
>            private string _consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerKey");
>            private string _consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerSecret");
>            private string _accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("accessToken");
>            private string _accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("accessTokenSecret");
>
>            private IHubContext _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TwitterHub>();
>
>            public TwitterConnection()
>            {
>                // Access the filtered stream
>              var filteredStream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();
>
>              filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => 
>              { 
>                  _context.Clients.All.broadcast(args.Tweet.Text);
>              };
>
>              filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();
>
>            }
>    }
>    ```
>
> 2. Point two
>
> As you can see, the code sample feature does not work when included in
>   a list. Does anyone know of any way around this? Or am I just being
>   stupid?
>
> Feel free to edit, to try and replicate the bug

The source:

```
Whilst posting an answer on SO, I noticed that code sample formatting did not work correctly when posting snippets of code in numbered or order lists. For example:

 1. Point one

        public class TwitterConnection {
                private string _consumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerKey");
                private string _consumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("consumerSecret");
                private string _accessKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("accessToken");
                private string _accessToken = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings.Get("accessTokenSecret");

                private IHubContext _context = GlobalHost.ConnectionManager.GetHubContext<TwitterHub>();

                public TwitterConnection()
                {
                    // Access the filtered stream
                    var filteredStream = Stream.CreateFilteredStream();

                    filteredStream.MatchingTweetReceived += (sender, args) => 
                    { 
                        _context.Clients.All.broadcast(args.Tweet.Text);
                    };

                    filteredStream.StartStreamMatchingAllConditions();

                }
        }

<!-- -->

2. Point two 


As you can see, the code sample feature does not work when included in a list. Does anyone know of any way around this? Or am I just being stupid?

Feel free to edit, to try and replicate the bug
```

As an aside, the indentation seems funky.

Comment: Why is it like that? That's very unpractical. For example, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14883687) had that issue, and I had to add four spaces on each line by hand since CTRL+K only adds/removes the first four spaces on each line. Can we get this fixed?

Comment: Consider using a trick: Adding a letter so you can use the indent-feature. And if you want to change it, describe exactly how it should work instead in a feature-request. It gets... far more complicated.

Comment: Why would it be more complicated? Wouldn't it work if four spaces at the beginning of a line just meant that it's code, no matter if it's in a list or not?

Comment: @DonaldDuck: Then how would you put a list in a list?

Comment: That's a good point. I found a feature request for fixing this issue [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300813/the-code-block-button-doesnt-work-properly-in-lists).

Comment: yeah it's really annoying .... still not fixed. For example when you start to write something without even hitting the list button - like `1. something` and then you want to use a code formatting in the new line, it simply doesn't work