# The code block button doesn't work properly in lists

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting

When you write code out, then you select it and hit the code button (or use the <kbd>K</kbd> + <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> combo).  It doesn't work properly in lists, and "breaks" the typical formatting....

- I'll start of a random list, then I'll try to use a code block here:

  let theDevelopers = "have a break";

As you can see, it only indents it to the list (probably by-design), and doesn't treat it code block...

There is two ways to solve this:

```
 - I'll start of a random list, then I'll try to use a code block here:

 <!-- Making a comment, to break the flow -->

    let theDevelopers = "have a break";
```

Or

```
- I'll start of a random list, then I'll try to use a code block here:


        let theDevelopers = "have a break";
        // Manually indenting all your code 4 more spaces.
```

Although these do render differently:

- I'll start of a random list, then I'll try to use a code block here:

```
let theDevelopers = "have a break";
```

and

- I'll start of a random list, then I'll try to use a code block here:

  ```
  let theDevelopers = "have a break";
  // Manually indenting all your code 4 more spaces.
  ```

My proposal is to replace the current functionality with two separate commands, one that indents, and one that dedents.

---

The main reason I wanted this to be fixed is because the button that creates the code block toggles, it doesn't append 4 lines every time.  So if you truly want to use a code block in a list, you have to indent manually (which can be quite the task, if you're posting a lot of code).

---

As mentioned in the comments, this is not a duplicate of the question linked....  This is a feature request to make it so the button and CTRL+K work properly in lists, or add separate functions (probably easier) to intended / dedent,

Comment: @Cerbrus, that's about the formatting itself, I'm talking about how the code button automatically formats it, it toggles, so you will always have to manually indent.  That's also why this is a [tag:feature-request] and not a [tag:bug]

Comment: It is not a duplicate. It is a feature-request to be able to indent automatically by a multiple of 4 spaces

Comment: @Cerbrus How can a [tag:feature-request] question be a duplicate of a [tag:bug] one ?

Answer (score 1):

It would be great to have two different commands one to indent and one to dedent. As a workaround, I generally add a line with a single char (`q` or `.`) after the block to indent and select it along with the block. As it now starts on first colum it is indented 4 spaces further. I just have to remove the useless line, or delete the for spaces and iterate if I want more indentation. But it is indeed just a poor man's workaround :-(

Comment: Instead of a single character, add: `<!---->`