# Automatically indent code the correct amount under numbered lists

Tags: feature-request, code-formatting, markdown, markdown-rendering

Code does not show correctly under a numbered list:

[image: Screenshot of some poorly formatted code]

I have found some questions about this, like
[Code block bug when following numbered list?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255372/code-block-bug-when-following-numbered-list), no one says that is a bug, and has a tag `status-bydesign` so I ask a new feature.

It took me some time to figure out how to make code show correctly under a numbered list. I found that Stack Overflow needs a double indent (eight spaces, not four) under a numbered list, but <kbd>Tab</kbd> does not work in the input box. Why not detect when a user clicks the code formatting button and automatically add the appropriate indent? It would be much more convenient.

Comment: indent 8 spaces.

Comment: I don't understand what feature you are proposing. That we automatically detect bad formatting and fix it up? I eagerly await your proposed implementation. Post it as an answer.

Comment: @bolov This would be much easier if the on-site editor actually provided a reasonable way to do so. When writing posts with more complex formatting, I usually find myself having to fall back to a text editor, format the post there, and then copy-paste into the page. And then prove that I'm not a robot, because I submitted a lot of text quickly...

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/300813/209139.

Comment: @Cody Gray I have posted the answer,  just say what I thought.

Comment: @Cerbrus I have relate that in quesion, no one says that is a bug, so I ask a feature.

Answer (score -1):

Normally, one paste his code under numbered list and click `code sample button` on editor,

he expect this:

1. below code start with indent space 8

   ```
   print 'hello'
   ```

Not this(current):

2. below code start with indent space 4

   print 'hello'

---

@Cody Gray I don't know the detail implementation of SO' editor, but I would say what I imagine:

Solution 1: When user click `code sample button`, automatically detect above text, if has a numbered list mark, add 8 space indent instead of 4 space indent.(simple, but may have some accident? I don't know)

Solution 2: Simply add a `add indent button`, user select a piece of text, click this button, just add 4 indent to this text, then all done.One can add indent in everywhere as his will.It seems SO not support multi level numbered list for now?Add this button also helpful for that, and I think this can solve @Angew 's problem more perfectly.